# How to set the picture in LaTeX in many positions

Tags: graphics, wrapfigure

[image: donald k]

I have a problem. My lecturer gave the task to make an article with LaTeX. but in one condition,  I can't set the picture like this. How to set a picture like this in LaTeX?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please have a look at the `wrapfig` package.

Comment: and also at our [Welcome to TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) page

Comment: @jjdb What was the intended layout? You mean the 'how ti [pic] i have a problem'?

Comment: @Troy, sorry, I was stupid. I maybe need first to drink my morning coffee before making stupid suggestions on this site. Now I leave and brew me a nice big coffee…Apologies again!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You also can use the plain TeX macro package `insbox`: the `\InsertBoxL` and `\InsertBoXR` commands require two mandatory arguments: the number of unshortened lines and it the contents of the box, and one optional argument (at the end): the number of supplementary lines to be shortened in case TeX doesn't make an exact calculation.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\input{insbox}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[11]
\InsertBoxL{3} {\fbox{\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}\includegraphics[scale=0.35]{pepe-le-pew1}\\\footnotesize Pepe le Pew\end{tabular}}\quad}[3]
\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `wrapfig` package. Below is a small example and for a quick start guide on it you should read the [wikibooks article on floats](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Floats,_Figures_and_Captions#Wrapping_text_around_figures).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
    \lipsum[1]
    \begin{wrapfigure}{l}{2cm}
        \includegraphics[width=2cm,height=3cm]{example-image}
    \end{wrapfigure}
    \lipsum[2-3]
\end{document}
```

Just because I have seen Bernards answer and figured you maybe want the lines around the picture I did an example with `wrapfig` and the use of the `tabular` environment. The `\vspace` and `\hspace` commands give it a better positioning in the text and ensure better/tighter spacing of the lines.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
    \lipsum[1]
    \begin{wrapfigure}{l}{2.3cm}
        \vspace{-10pt}
        \begin{tabular}{ | @{\hspace{3pt}} c @{\hspace{3pt}} | }
            \hline \vspace{-2\tabcolsep}\vspace{3pt} \\
            \includegraphics[width=2cm,height=3cm]{example-image} \\
            \footnotesize{Text} \\
            \hline 
        \end{tabular}
        \vspace{-10pt}
    \end{wrapfigure}
    \lipsum[2-3]
\end{document}
```

[image]